# Wordpress Admin doesn't load css files and images

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

I'm having a serious problem. I have wordpress 3.9 installed on my server. the problem is that my website front end loads good, but my back end just loads text :
[image]

I have updated/reinstalled wordpress but nothing has happend. What should I do?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 100% sure that if you simply do the following, you'll figure out what's wrong and fix it.

1. [Deactivate all plugins](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-deactivate-all-plugins-when-not-able-to-access-wp-admin/) without use of your WP-Admin.
2. Activate them, 2 or 3 at a time, and determine which plugin is the culprit
3. If none of these plugins are the culprit, go to the [WordPress site](https://wordpress.org/download/) and download WordPress.  With an FTP utility such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or another client if you already have one, then upload **the entire wp-admin folder** to your server, overwriting older files.

Your WordPress admin will be fine after these steps.  And of course, **never** alter any core WordPress files -- **ever**.  The only files you should ever tinker with are files in your child theme, which is something you should be using.

Comment: p.s. -- I know when one tells you to "deactivate all plugins", it can seem like a time-consuming process.  On one domain, I have 56 active plugins (page load times under 2 seconds, 'cause they're well-coded plugins), and I can deactivate 'em and find a culprit, then reactivate 'em in under 2 minutes.

Comment: This is happening after a fresh install with plugins deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

Would be great to have a bit more information about this topic. First of all: Is this a new problem respectively did the admin run without errors before? (3.9 sounds like the page is not a new clean install).

Usually I would start debugging the page via e.g. firebug => Check the Stats of the CSS-Files.

If they load correctly (200) check if they are empty or incomplete (Incompleteness can be checked via diff against the original file ... most IDEs will handle that for you)! If they aren't you have probably just diabled CSS in your browser for the URL of the admin-panel.

If they don't load, try to check why! If the files exist its most probably an error in your .htaccess (wrong rewrite, blocked directory, etc.).